# Find all natural from the format: $2^{n}-1,n\in\Bbb N^{*}$ such that: $\begin{cases}2^{n}-1<10^{5}\\2^{n}-1=pq \:(\text{distinct primes})\end{cases}$

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers

Problem :

Find all natural from the format : $2^{n}-1,n\in \mathbb N^{*}$ they are less then $10^{5}$ and written as product two different $p,q$ prime numbers

My try :

$n=1$ so $1<10^{5}$  $×$

$n=2$ so $3<10^{5}$ but $3≠p.q$ , $p,q=$ prime number $×$

$n=3$ so $7<10^{5}$ but $7≠p.q$ $×$

$n=4$ so $15<10^{5}$ and $15=3.5$ $√$

But I need method to find all this number ??

Comment: $2^{17}-1>10^5$, so you don't have very many more to check

Comment: $2^p-1$ with $p\in\{2,3,5,7,13\}$ is (Mersenne) prime

Comment: $2^{2k}-1=(2^k-1)(2^k+1)$

Comment: @J.W.Tanner what about $n=$ odd

Comment: I'm sure there are tables of factorizations of Mersenne numbers somewhere on the web. There are also programs to do factorizations. And there's the Online Encyclopedia of Integer Sequences.

Comment: more over $gcd(2^k-1,2^j-1)=2^{gcd(k,j)}-1$

Comment: @EllenEllen:  for $n$ odd $2^n-1$ could be prime (cf. my comment about Mersenne primes above), though $2^{3k}-1=(2^k-1)(2^{2k}+2^k+1)$

Comment: It looks like you already have a method for finding these numbers: Take the numbers $n$ one by one, compute and factor $2^n-1$, keep the ones that have just two prime factors, and (importantly!) stop when $2^n-1$ is bigger than $10^5$. What more do you need? (I ask this seriously. If you are looking for a more *efficient* method, that doesn't rely so heavily on trial-and-error computation, then it would help to edit the question to say so explicitly.)

Answer (score 1):

For $n=2k$, $2^n-1=(2^k+1)(2^k-1)$.

Factorizations of $2^n-1$ for $n=2k+1$ can be found in the [Cunningham tables](https://homes.cerias.purdue.edu/~ssw/cun/third/pmain901).

For $n=2, 3, 5, 7$, or $13$, $2^n-1$ is prime.

With this information, you should be able to answer your question.

Comment: Thank you very much @J.W.Tanner , but if $n=$ odd then how I prove it ??

Comment: how you prove what?

Comment: How I prove $n=$ only odd

Comment: He never said that. he said that for odd $n$ you can check a table. In general if $n=2^jk$ then it applies his factorization of $2^n-1$ ; $j$ times and has at least $j$ factors. Similar if you found a factorization of $2^n-1$ when it's divisible by 3, etc.